# How do I gzip files from different folders, with each file in its own folder

Tags: batch, 7-zip

i would to gzip all the html files in all directories which are under a directory, while deleting the uncompressed files.

```
for /r %%i in (*.html) do "c:\7-zip\7z.exe" a -aoa -mx=9 -tgzip -sdel "%%~ni.gz" "%%i"
```

This command line partially works but does not gzip each html file in its directory, instead it gzips all in the parent directory.

if i do this

```
for /r %%i in (*.html) do "c:\7-zip\7z.exe" a -aoa -mx=9 -tgzip -sdel "%%i.gz" "%%i"
```

it gzips each file in its directory but keep .html

i have got the solution

```
for /r %%i in (*.html) do "c:\7-zip\7z.exe" a -aoa -mx=9 -tgzip -sdel "%%~pni.gz" "%%i"
```

Comment: zoom - What's up, you still there and need help with this?

Comment: @zoom, use `cd` to change to the directory of the file to compress thatway 7zip's output goes there. You can also use `c:\7-zip\7z.exe -o WhereYouWantTheOutputToGo`